# Error converting data type varchar to numeric -joining tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am not able to join two columns with different data types.

`main_ref_id` is `char` and `person_id` are `numeric`

Query:

```
 select 
     main_ref_id 
 from 
     not 
 where 
     main_ref_type = 'P' 
     and convert(numeric(9, 0), main_ref_id) in (select cast(person_id as numeric) 
                                                 from person_wo_memberships)
```

Error

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Any help???

Comment: can you share your table structure, also you can try joining column without converting into number. Just join them as string.

Comment: You're converting `main_ref_id` to NUMERIC(9,0) and `person_id` to NUMERIC(18,0). Have you looked at the data in those two columns to see if there are any non-numeric values? What are they're data types? And I'm not convinced that the `from not where` syntax makes sense. Any other dragon dropping errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have stated that `main_ref_id` is `char`, but you are trying to convert that into a `numeric` value. The error is self-explanatory.

Try converting `person_id`, which is `numeric` to `char`

```
select main_ref_id 
from [not] 
where main_ref_type='P' and
main_ref_id in 
     (select cast(person_id as varchar) 
      from person_wo_memberships )
```

Please define the length of `varchar` in the `cast` statement, to match the length of `main_ref_id`